# PHP not getting the right string from variable

Tags: php

i have made 2 variables with names of :

```
$strin = '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>';
$strin2 = '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>';
```

and on output i must get like this :

```
<div id="div1">HERE WHAT EVER I TYPED ON TEXT AREA 1</div>
```

but i only get on output the word that i type on text area 1 without div that means i am not getting what is in variable. not sure what is wrong

same for text area 2

here is my php code

```
<form method="post"> 
<label>File name:</label><br> 
<input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='File name'> 
<label>Folders:</label> 
<select name="thisfolder"> 
<option value="">Default</option> 
<option value="Folder1">Folder1</option> 
<option value="Folder2">Folder2</option> 
<option value="Folder3">Folder3</option> 
</select><br><br> 
<label>Text Area 1:</label><br> 
<textarea type='text' name='strin' style="margin:0px;width:500px;height:200px;"></textarea><br><br> 
<label>Text Area 2:</label><br> 
<textarea type='text' name='strin2' style="margin:0px;width:500px;height:200px;"></textarea><br> 
<input type='submit' value='Add'> 
</form> 

<script> 
var textarea1 = document.querySelector('[name=strin]'); 
var textarea2 = document.querySelector('[name=strin2]'); 

textarea1.oninput = function () { 
textarea2.value = ''; 
}; 

textarea2.oninput = function () { 
textarea1.value = ''; 
}; 
</script> 

<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{ 
// the name of the file to create 
$filename=$_POST['filename']; 
// the name of the file to be in page created 
$strin=$_POST['strin']; 
// the name of the file to be in page created 
$strin2=$_POST['strin2']; 
// the name of the folder to put $filename in 
$thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder']; 
// make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder 
if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder)) { 
// if not, we need to make a new folder 
mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder); 
} 
// . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php 
$myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php"; 

// This is another way of writing an if statment 
$iframe = ($strin !== '') ? $strin : $strin2; 
$strin = '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>';
$strin2 = '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>';



$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
$stringData = "

    <div id=\"area_code\">

        " .$iframe. "

    </div>

"; 

fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
fclose($fh); 
} 
?>
```

hope you get the idea.

Comment: *"// This is another way of writing an if statment"* -- not it's not. [`?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) is an operator, not a statement. The operators are used to connect expressions into larger ones. An expressions is evaluated, it has a value. A statement doesn't have a value; it is an action.

Comment: Debug your code, check if POST's are not empty, var_dump(); and die(); your best friends here.

Comment: Also, you don't have any `action` tag in your form.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this a little while ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579686/php-trying-to-add-string-and-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP trying to add string and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579686/php-trying-to-add-string-and-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code evaluated the values of `$strin` and `$strin2` too early. You need to change the following code:

```
// This is another way of writing an if statment 
$iframe = ($strin !== '') ? $strin : $strin2; 
$strin = '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>';
$strin2 = '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>';
```

to this:

```
// This is another way of writing an if statment 
$iframe = ($strin !== '') ? '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>' : '<div id="div1">'.$strin2.'</div>';
```

So `$strin` and `$strin2` are appropriately updated before `$iframe` is evaluated

Comment: yeah i got it same way but your answer is right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$iframe = ($strin !== '') ? $strin : $strin2; 
$strin = '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>';
$strin2 = '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>';
```

You copy the value of `$strin` or `$strin2` into `$iframe` then you modify `$strin` and `$strin2` and you expect that somehow the value of `$iframe` is updated too.

This doesn't happen. The code does exactly what is written above. If you don't put a different value in `$iframe` later then it doesn't change.

It's not clear for me what you want to achieve. I guess you should use a real `if` statement (no, `?:` is not a shorter way to write an `if` statement; `?:` is an [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php), not a [statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)) and put the desired value in `$iframe`:

```
if ($string != '') {
    $iframe = '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>';
} else {
    $iframe = '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>';
}
```